# What does html.oldie mean in CSS?

Tags: css

I found a line of code in CSS:

```
html.oldie .hero-gallery {
    height: 860px
}
```

What does `html.oldie` mean? I am guessing that this is for viewing of the HTML in different browsers, but I don't know exactly what this means.

Answer (score 2):

`.oldie` is just a class. It's taking an element of class `.hero-gallery` inside an `html` tag of class `.oldie` and setting it's height property to 860px. The HTML might look something like this:

```
<html class="oldie">
    <!-- some HTML here -->
    <div class="hero-gallery">
        <!-- HTML for the gallery -->
    </div>
</html>
```

It's odd to see a class on the `html` element, but it's not any different from a class on any other element as far as CSS is concerned.

Answer (score 2):

The `.oldie` class is a bit of CSS written by Jonathan Neal. It "tranforms (sic) CSS to be compatible with old Internet Explorer." It is documented [here.](http://jonathantneal.github.io/oldie) It is meant to ensure that HTML5/CSS3 works in IE8.